# Microsoft Access 2007: searching a string within a memo field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to make a 'search engine' for looking up a user specified string into a memo field. I've made several attempts using a query and 'Like' operator on memo field or even attempting to convert the memo field into a string (using CStr) with no success.
Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying? A filter on a form? A query? Please post an example, even if it does not work the way you wish.

Comment: I asked [this same question but for web databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125737/microsoft-access-search-memo-field-in-web-database) made with Access 2010, if anyone cares to answer it!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i get u'r question but you can use VBA to solve that: 
copy the memo field into a string

```
    findStr = MyForm.MySearch
    memoStr = MyForm.MyMemo
```

an use this

```
    pos = InStr(memoStr, findStr)
    If pos > 0 Then 'String found at position pos
```